# Is the structure used for these web pages a design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net

I want to know if the structure for an ASP.NET website I'm working on uses a design pattern for it's web pages. If it is a design pattern, what is it called? The web pages have the following structure:

[image]

UserDetails page (UserDetails.aspx) - includes UserDetailsController.ascx user control. UserDetailsController.ascx includes sub user controls like UserAccountDetails.ascx and UserLoginDetails.ascx etc

Each sub user control contains a small amount of code/logic, the 'controller' user controls that host these sub user controls (i.e UserDetailsController.ascx) appear to call the business rules code and pass the data to the sub user controls.

Is this a design pattern? What is it called?

Comment: looks like variation of Master page design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: looks like a variation of a Master-child design.

Long answer: there are different standards how UI pattern is defined. To express them, i have combined listing that might be helpful to expand on this topic.

- [UI Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- [UI Design patterns Introduction](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/salaakso/patterns/index.html)
- [40+ Helpful Resources On User Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)
- [MSDN - Design and Implementation Guidelines for Web Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647343.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Design Patterns](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/276/design-patterns/)